# Make commits as Gitlab user

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Sorry if its stupid question, i am just learning now.

I have name and email set in git like name and email in Gitlab, but in commits it doesnt show my Gitlab account and just sent me to other mail program.  How can i make commits as Gitlab user?

I used that command to set name with email and its the same as in Gitlab.

```
git config user.name "Your Full name"
git config user.email "your_email@example.com"
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Any idea where this other mail is set ?

Comment: You have to set once your user and email:
`git config --global user.name "Your Full name"`
`git config --global user.email your_email@example.com`